# R analysis of number of mature animals

Tags: r

I am a complete beginner so bare with me :D

I did an experiment where I noted the number of mature animals for my ten different treatments on day 4 to day 12. I now want to see whether there is a difference in this increase, so whether a certain treatment might see animals mature faster than others. Per treatment I have six replicates.

So the idea is to make a graph where i see the increasing number of mature animals from day 4 to day 12, with one regression line for each treatment. I then want to compare to see whether they actually differ, probably by using the slope?

So my data looks like this:

```
Treatment      Replicate     Mature_D4  ... Mature_D12

Control        1             0              12
Control        2             0              12
Control        3             1              11
Control        4             0              9
Control        5             1              8
Control        6             0              12
Treatment 1    1             0              7
...
Treatment 9    6             1              8
```

I have a lot of NAs and clearly left-skewed data.

I thought about a glm() because it is count data. I am wondering if I could do all treatments in one glm() but don't know how to extract the slope for each treatment. Or I could do a glm() for each treatment seperately but then I need to check the assumptions for each, and what if they are not met or I need another model? Is it a bad idea to compare the slope of different models?

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow, Cato. Your question sounds more about the choice of (statistical) method and workflow than their specific implementation in R language. It might be more efficient to first research over at: https://stats.stackexchange.com/ and, in case, come back for technical details .

Comment: Are the 6 treatments 6 different treaments or the same treatment with 6 different doses?

Answer (score 0):

As there is a temporal element, I guess your first step would be to create a line plot where you have time on x axis and number of mature on y. And you will have a line for each treatment. You might want to consider a time series analysis if interested in all time points. Depending on your experiment an idea could be of just looking at the last time of observation; you can create a new variable which is the difference of mature at t_final - mature at t_start. This new variable could be your dependent variable for a linear regression. The predictor would be the categorical variable of treatment group (use control group as baseline for the categorical comparison).
I don't think you want to do separate regressions, as you are trying to estimate the effect of treatment, so that is your independent variable.